# MySQL data backup using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am here stuck with an problem and really need you people's help. I am trying to export mysql data using a PHP script. But the problem is an error which is below
"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted....". I have seen some posts where they have suggested to change the php.ini file. But as I am hosted on a dedicated server I do not have that access. The table that I am trying to export has more the 2.2GB of data. I am here by posting the function that I am using to export those datas. Can you guys please help me in solving this issues?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
backup_tables('hostname','username','password','databasename');

function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$table = 'Table Name')
{

$link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($name,$link);

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

$row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
$return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
$return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++)
{
$row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
$row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
}
$return.= ");\n";
}
}
$return.="\n\n\n";
//save file
$handle = fopen('db-backup-'.time().'-'.($tables).'.sql','w+');
fwrite($handle,$return);
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: You probably want to divide the work into different parts, where you export a part of the table each time.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to do this using PHP, rather than (say) schedule mysqldump to do it for you?

Comment: Actually as I am using a shared server and they are not allowing me to store more then 2GB data in a single table. So I have move those data to a dedicated server. So want the backup for that.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you are trying to remake a wheel here. Mysql has a fantastic [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) executable that will quickly, quietly and using few resources generate the file you are making. The best thing is that you can actually call it directly from within a php script using [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) with something like this:

```
exec('mysqldump --user=... --password=... --host=... DB_NAME > /path/to/output/file.sql');
```

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP is making a SQL text file that will re-create his table. This does the same thing, except faster, using very few resources and in a safe manner.

Comment: @Aelios It will happily export a 10 row database or one with billions of rows.

Answer (score 1):

> The table that I am trying to export has more the 2.2GB of data

And you're trying to load it all into a PHP array.

Even if you had enough memory, the performance would be appalling.

Write the rows fetched from the database as you read them...

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
   fputs($outfile, 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(');
   ....
}
```

But a far better solution would be to use mysqldump.

**update**

I forgot to say that your method for escaping the output is wrong - use mysql_escape_string() not addslashes + ereg_replace() (and if you must use string relpacement functions, str_replace is much faster then [ep]reg_replace).

Comment: I have access to phpmyadmin. When I am using the "Export" option. The connection gets reset. So throwing an error when trying with that. Can you suggest something through phpmyadmin . I also have FTP details. But nothing more then that

Comment: Then you're going to have to take a very different tack. Regardles of how you implement it, it will take a very long time to extract the data. HTTP is not designed for doing things which take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to zip your backup sql statement with `Zip->addFromString`

http://php.net/manual/fr/book.zip.php

http://php.net/manual/fr/zip.examples.php

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./backup.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("Could not open <$filename>\n");
}
$zip->addFromString("backup.txt", "sql statement");
$zip->close();
?>
```

Try to divide your backup into several zip file (for example : one table by zip)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collecting everything into (a huge) `$return`, move the `fopen` call to the start of the function and write every piece of result directly using `fwrite` instead of adding it to `$return`. The memory problem you're encountering is because `$return` takes up so much space.

Comment: See symcbean's answer. I agree with him and others that `mysqldump` would be the better option though.

Answer (score 0):

hm.. i guess the best way to do this is using sql query ["SELECT * INTO OUTFILE..."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html) because php function "exec" can be forbidden by php.ini safe mode.